# Prove $\sum \sqrt{a_n b_n}$ converges if $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converge.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Help please!

Prove $\sum \sqrt{a_n b_n}$ converges if $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converge.

I can prove that $\sum a_n b_n$ converges but couldn't for $\sum \sqrt{a_n b_n}$.

Thank you.

EDIT: $a_n, b_n \ge 0 \;\forall n$

Comment: I assume that $a_n, b_n\ge 0$... ?

Comment: The question doesn’t state that $a_n,b_n\ge 0$.  Without this it is clearly false by taking both to be the same conditionally-convergent series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\sqrt {AB}\le  A+B
$$
because of $(\sqrt A - \sqrt B)^2 \ge 0$.

Note: Similar can be shown to hold true for $A_1, ..., A_n$ and $A_1, A_2, ...$

Comment: We assume that it can be shown by induction that similar holds true for both $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ and $A_1, A_2,...$ ?

Comment: we can do it :)

Comment: mookid, the point is the extension to $\infty$ is true but not trivial...

Comment: this is a special case of Jensen's inequality.